# How to import google drive videos into same youtube account?

Tags: google-api, youtube, google-drive-api, youtube-api

I have already uploaded videos available in google drive. How to import these videos into same youtube account to watch those videos in android MI tv ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google drive and YouTube are to separate web applications.

You will need to download the files from google drive and the upload them to YouTube its not possible to upload directly from drive.

How you do this will depend entirely on which programming language you are using.

But basically use Oauth2 to login a user to google drive and YouTube. Programmatic download the file to where ever you are running your application from then upload it to Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

you could select video in google drive and select upload to you tube Chanel like below:

[image]

and use this website:

https://imclient.herokuapp.com

Comment: what is the relevance of the link you provided?